# WPF - Tabcontrol - Tab Item with DataGrid jumps if I switch tabs

Tags: wpf, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

In the below WPF XAML I have a tab control with 3 tabs, the content in the second tab jumps while switching tabs. If I comment out the DataGrid markup and try it works without any issue. Not sure If it's causing because of DataGrid.

```
<Border Background="GhostWhite" Name="SPCBorder" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Visibility="{Binding Path=ButtonSPCVisibility}">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Grid>
      <TabControl Style="{StaticResource TabControlStyleSPC}" Margin="10">
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyleSPC}">
          <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="Search SPC"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </TabItem.Header>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                                    
            <Label Grid.Row="0" Margin="15,0,0,10">Deal Number:</Label>
            <TextBox Height="30" Name="SPCSearchDealNumTextBox" Grid.Row="1"
                     Width="180" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="15,0,0,10"
                     Text="{Binding DealNumSPC}"/>
            <Button Content="Search SPC" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="110" Height="30"
                    FontWeight="Bold" Name="btnSPCSearch"
                    Command="{Binding AddSPCDeals}" Margin="0,10,0,10"/>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" CanContentScroll="True"
                          HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                          Margin="25,15,10,20" >
              <DataGrid Name="SPCSearchDataGrid" FontFamily="Calibri" Height="350"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding DealsAddedSPC, Mode=TwoWay}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HeadersVisibility="Column" Background="White" FontSize="15"
                        GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        IsReadOnly="True"
                        ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnStlye}"
                        RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal Number" Binding="{Binding DealNumber}" Width="100"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal Description" Binding="{Binding DealDesc}" Width="300"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Width="300"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal BeginDate" Binding="{Binding DealBeg,StringFormat={}{0:d}}" Width="200"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal EndDate" Binding="{Binding DealEnd,StringFormat={}{0:d}}" Width="200"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Org ID" Binding="{Binding OrgId}"/>
                  <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Customer #" Binding="{Binding EucNr}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
              </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyleSPC}">
          <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="Create SPC"/>                                        
            </StackPanel>
          </TabItem.Header>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <GroupBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5">
              <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Special Pricing Code - Details"></TextBlock>
              </GroupBox.Header>
              <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Customer Engagement</Label>
                  <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" ItemsSource="{Binding CustEngagementListSPC}"
                            SelectedValuePath="CustChannelID" DisplayMemberPath="CustChannelDesc"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding specialPricingCode.CustChannelId}"
                            Height="30" Name="CustEgmtSPC" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Publication Type</Label>
                  <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding specialPricingCode.PublicationType}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Content" Height="30"
                            Name="PublicationType" Width="250" FontSize="15">
                    <ComboBoxItem Name="pubTypeItemSelect">Select</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Name="pubTypeItem1">Listed</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem Name="pubTypeItem2">Unlisted</ComboBoxItem>
                  </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Visibility Level</Label>
                  <ComboBox SelectedIndex="0" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            SelectedValue="{Binding specialPricingCode.VisibilityLevel}"
                            SelectedValuePath="Content" Height="30"
                            Name="Visibilitylevel" Width="250" FontSize="15">
                    <ComboBoxItem  Name="VisibilitylevelSelect">Select</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem  Name="VisibilitylevelItem1">External</ComboBoxItem>
                    <ComboBoxItem  Name="VisibilitylevelItem2">Internal</ComboBoxItem>
                  </ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5 5 0 5">
              <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Assignment Type - Deal Inclusion"></TextBlock>
              </GroupBox.Header>
              <StackPanel Grid.Column="0">
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Geo Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15"
                            Opacity="1" Name="DealInclusionGeoCodeCombo"
                            IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></ComboBox>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Customer Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealInclusionCustCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Program Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealInclusionPrmCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Local Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealInclusionLocalCodeCombo"
                            IsTextSearchEnabled="True" IsEditable="True"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="4" Margin="5 5 0 5" Grid.Column="1">
              <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Assignment Type - Deal Exclusion"></TextBlock>
              </GroupBox.Header>
              <StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Geo Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealExclusionGeoCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Customer Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealExclusionCustCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Program Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealExclusionPrmCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel Margin="10 10 10 0" Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <Label Width="200">Local Code:</Label>
                  <ComboBox Height="30" Width="250" FontSize="15" Opacity="1"
                            Name="DealExclusionLocalCodeCombo" IsTextSearchEnabled="True"
                            IsEditable="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                </StackPanel>
              </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
            <GroupBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Margin="5 5 0 5">
              <GroupBox.Header>
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="Deal Added List"></TextBlock>
              </GroupBox.Header>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Button Content="Authorize Deals" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="110"
                        Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" Name="btnSPCAddDeal"
                        Command="{Binding AddSPCDeals}" Margin="240,10,15,10" />
                <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="25,15,10,20">
                  <DataGrid Name="SPCDealsDataGrid" FontFamily="Calibri"
                            SelectionMode="Extended" Height="350"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding DealsAddedSPC, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HeadersVisibility="Column"
                            Background="White" FontSize="15"
                            GridLinesVisibility="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            IsReadOnly="True"
                            ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnStlye}"
                            RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal Number" Binding="{Binding DealNumber}" Width="100"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal Description" Binding="{Binding DealDesc}" Width="300"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Company Name" Binding="{Binding CompanyName}" Width="300"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal BeginDate" Binding="{Binding DealBeg,StringFormat={}{0:d}}" Width="200"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Deal EndDate" Binding="{Binding DealEnd,StringFormat={}{0:d}}" Width="200"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Org ID" Binding="{Binding OrgId}"/>
                      <DataGridTextColumn Width="200" Header="Customer #" Binding="{Binding EucNr}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                  </DataGrid>
                </ScrollViewer>
                <Button Content="Save SPC" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="100"
                        Height="30" FontWeight="Bold" Name="btnSaveSPC"
                        Command="{Binding SaveSPC}" Margin="240,10,15,10"/>
              </StackPanel>
            </GroupBox>
          </Grid>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Style="{StaticResource TabItemStyleSPC}">
          <TabItem.Header>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
              <TextBlock Text="Inclusion-Exclusion"/>
            </StackPanel>
          </TabItem.Header>
        </TabItem>
      </TabControl>
    </Grid>
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

UPDATE: I have added styles of Tab Control and Tab Item

```
<!--Stlye for SPC Tabs-->
<Style x:Key="TabControlStyleSPC" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
  <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
        <Grid KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <TabPanel x:Name="HeaderPanel"
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Panel.ZIndex="1"
                    Margin="0,0,4,-1"
                    IsItemsHost="True"
                    KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1"
                    Background="Transparent"/>
          <Border x:Name="Border"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  BorderThickness="2"
                  CornerRadius="2"
                  KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local"
                  KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained"
                  KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2"
                  BorderBrush="LightGray">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost" Margin="4" ContentSource="SelectedContent"/>
          </Border>
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Style for SPC Tab Visual-->
<Style x:Key="MyFocusVisualStyte" >
  <Setter Property="Control.Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate>
        <Border x:Name="FocusStyle" Background="#4433b4ed"/>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<!--Style for SPC Tab Item-->
<Style x:Key="TabItemStyleSPC" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
  <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15"/>
  <!--<Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>-->
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF474747"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource MyFocusVisualStyte}" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
          <Storyboard x:Key="StartAction">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border1Highlited" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border2Highlited" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" From="0" To="1" Duration="0:0:0.5"/>
          </Storyboard>
          <Storyboard x:Key="ExitAction">
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border1Highlited" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border2Highlited" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.3" />
          </Storyboard>
        </ControlTemplate.Resources>

        <Grid x:Name="Root">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="6"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2"/>
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Border x:Name="Border" Margin="0,0,-1,0" Background="#ededed">
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentSite"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              Margin="30,10,30,4"
                              RecognizesAccessKey="True"/>
          </Border>
          <Border Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,10,0,4" Background="#d6d6d6"/>
          <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#ededed"/>
          <Border Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border1Highlited" Background="Transparent"/>
          <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="#c9c9c9"/>
          <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Border2Highlited" Background="Transparent"/>

        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="100" />
            <Setter TargetName="Border1Highlited" Property="Background" Value="#6CE26C"/>
            <Setter TargetName="Border2Highlited" Property="Background" Value="#6CE26C"/>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource StartAction}"/>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
              <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource ExitAction}"/>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#cccccc"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Add all relevant styles like "TabControlStyleSPC", TabItemStyleSPC etc. so that one can reproduce what you have tried.

Comment: @NareshRavlani I Have added the styles used for Tab Control.

Comment: What do you mean by _"the content in the second tab **jumps**"_? Does it move? Disappear?